# Testing a fragment (Android), mocking getActivity() call

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing

I want to test a Fragment with AndroidTest cases and Mockito (I am using mockito for other test cases).

I´ve done this before with my own code (coded in a different way) but in this case, I am testing a Fragment and I want to mock this call:  final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();

I will put you here part of the TestClass, and part of the Fragment that I want to test.
Thanks in advance for your ideas or suggestions.

```
public class MyFragmentTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity>{

    MyFragment myFragment;

    public MyFragmentTest () {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }

   @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        // This have to be done because of some issues with dexmaker
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", "/sdcard");
        // This have to be done because of the sharedUserId problem
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
            getClass().getClassLoader());

        myFragment = new MyFragment() {
             //I can override methods here
        };

    }

    public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
        myFragment.methodThatIWantToTest();
    }

}


 /************  CLASS THAT I WANT TO TEST *********/
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

     public void methodThatIWantToTest(){
        /*..... more lines */
        final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        /*..... more lines ...*/
     }
```

}

Comment: What is getActivity() and where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have employed this hack:

```
// Needed because Fragment.mActivity is package-private
package android.support.v4.app;

public class FragmentInjector {
    public static void injectActivity(Fragment fragment, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        fragment.mActivity = fragmentActivity;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could employ reflection to change the value of `fragment.mActivity`.  I don't know of any other way.

Comment: For me works with reflection changing the value, because I don´t want to apply a hack in a generic aspect.  Thanks!

Comment: how to use this piece of code, can you give some complete context, where to apply this class? thx

Comment: @VanessaRomanoSobrino Can you please share your code